# Why can't I drop this FOREIGN KEY Constraint for my accounts table?

Tags: postgresql

I have an `accounts` table that has this `FOREIGN KEY` constraint on it:

```
TABLE "edits" CONSTRAINT "edits_account_id_fkey1" FOREIGN KEY (account_id) REFERENCES accounts(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
```

I want to drop this constraint but everytime I try to execute this command below:

```
ALTER TABLE accounts DROP CONSTRAINT edits_account_id_fkey1;
```

I get this error:

```
ERROR:  constraint "edits_account_id_fkey1" of relation "accounts" does not exist
```

It clearly exists. I am looking at it with the `\d accounts` command. Why is this happening?

-------------EDIT-----------

`accounts`

```
    Indexes:
       ........
    Check constraint:
       ......

    Foreign-key constraints:
      "accounts_about_markup_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (about_markup_id) REFERENCES markups(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
      "accounts_best_vita_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (best_vita_id) REFERENCES vitae(id)
      "accounts_organization_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (organization_id) REFERENCES organizations(id) ON DELETE CASCADE

    Referenced by:
      TABLE "account_reports" CONSTRAINT "account_reports_account_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (account_id) REFERENCES accounts(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
      TABLE "actions" CONSTRAINT "actions_account_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (account_id) REFERENCES accounts(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
      TABLE "api_keys" CONSTRAINT "api_keys_account_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (account_id) REFERENCES accounts(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
      TABLE "authorizations" CONSTRAINT "authorizations_account_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (account_id) REFERENCES accounts(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
      TABLE "positions" CONSTRAINT "claims_account_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (account_id) REFERENCES accounts(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
      TABLE "duplicates" CONSTRAINT "duplicates_account_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (account_id) REFERENCES accounts(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
      TABLE "old_edits" CONSTRAINT "edits_account_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (account_id) REFERENCES accounts(id)
      TABLE "edits" CONSTRAINT "edits_account_id_fkey1" FOREIGN KEY (account_id) REFERENCES accounts(id) ON DELETE CASCADE

      etc...... etc......
```

Comment: I don't see a constraint named `edits_account_id_fkey1` in that output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The constraint is placed on the table `edits`, but you're altering the table `accounts`. Change `accounts` in the query to `edits` and then it will work.